# Python 3: Extracting rows of text from a HTML (.txt) site onto Jupyter notebook

Tags: python

Brand new to Python and only 2 days in. I am trying to extract specific rows of text from a HTML to Jupyter notebook which will then be transfered to a Csv or a xlsx. I used the following approach:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/wa_gr101.txt")
txt=response.text
print(txt) #This is essentially prints the entire txt file onto Jupyter

f=open("txt")
lines=f.readlines()
print (lines[28])
```

The error message I get at this point is:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-fc336b724c2c> in <module>()
----> 1 f=open("txt")
      2 lines=f.readlines()
      3 print (lines[28])

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'txt'
```

Must I import or nest the file within Jupyter Notebook or is there a smarter way to go about this? Sorry if this question sounds too newbie.

Thanks all!

Comment: The error is originated by the fact, that the file does not exist yet. If you want to write it you have to use open("txt", "w"). Then again, readline will fail for a file that did not exist priorly and is opened for writing. So what do you want to do exactly? Do you want to write the content of your txt variable to a file?

Comment: Hi Tristan, it would be ideal to grab the text directly from the HTML source rather than manually saving it in the local computer and onto the directory that IPython refers to. Is there a way to do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to iterate through the lines in the file returned. For this you don't even need to use the *open* function at all since your data isn't saved in a file. It's already stored in a variable for you. You just need to split the data into lines and then iterate through them. Something like this should work:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/wa_gr101.txt")
txt=response.text
print(txt) #This is essentially prints the entire txt file onto Jupyter


# split the text wherever you find a newline
lines = txt.split('\n') 

# print line at index 28 (the 29th line)
print(lines[28]) 

# or iterate through the data
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

PS: The error in your code is caused by the line *f=open("txt")*. The *open* function is used to read from files, not from variables. If you save the data in variable *txt* to a file called data.txt then you could read it as *f=open("data.txt")*

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks everyone for your help. Much much appreciated!